# Creating tree editor for mptt model in django admin

Tags: python, django, mptt, feincms

I'm trying to create a GUI editor for a configuration format using django admin. I don't really need to display anything on the main site, since the data in the admin will be used to generate configuration files.

As part of this I need a way to add and edit a configuration tree of models.  I've had a look at mptt and the tree editor in feincms, however I can't get the example at http://feincms-django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/v1.9.5/admin.html#putting-it-all-together to work. Is there a simple working example I can look at?

I'm open to other suggestions for how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own problem, my solution is at https://github.com/pj/feincms_tree_example if anyone is interested.